# NHibernate 3 lazy properties and eager queries

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I'm using NHibernate 3.0.0 and the new feature lazy properties. However, in some queries I want to eagerly load the properties and I would like the query to result in non-proxied entity instances. I also prefer to use the LINQ provider or QueryOver. So my two questions related to this are:

1. I know that eager loading of
   properties can be achieved in HQL
   with "fetch all properties" but is
   it possible to do the same with the
   LINQ provider or QueryOver?
2. If I execute an HQL query with "fetch all properties" the entities in the result are indeed eagerly loaded but they are still proxied. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Cheers

Comment: What's the issue specifically with having proxied entities?

Comment: Transmitting the entity using WCF won't work, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For question 1**: The answer is no, 'fetch all properties' as described in http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties is currently only supported in HQL.

I do remember seeing in the NH Google Discussions somewhere, I'm unable to find the thread. Will update answer if I can find it today. But as of the current 3.1 release it's only in HQL.

**For question 2**: I don't know if there is a way to avoid this, I usually transform them to DTO's and serialize the DTO, not the NH Poco, when using WCF. Leonardo's link looks interesting and may be able to help.

Comment: @Yhrn - Sorry mate, can't find the thread on NHUsers to do with someone asking if it will be in NH3 or future releases. However did find that you can eager fetch the properties if you include them in a projection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/
to disable de lazy load of your classes (no proxies)
You can use this http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching
to eager load your properties
Or you can try this http://www.timvasil.com/blog14/post/2008/02/WCF-serialization-with-NHibernate.aspx
and still use the proxies.

Comment: The fetching of properties in your link is to do with relationships, not specific columns. Such as a lazy-loading/eager-loading the 'content' property of a 'post'. Yhrn is talking about http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties which is not supported by anything other than HQL at the moment.

Comment: You are right Phill. I read the question too fast and answered it wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Phill I believe that you are right and that the answers both my questions are simply "no" (at least for now, who knows what future releases might bring). If you feel confident about that, feel free to convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.