# How to run NHibernate run DB function for each member in a list

Tags: nhibernate

I have a DB-intensive function defined in MS SQL that computes a read-only property (`LastCompletedDate`) of an `Inspection` object. I don't usually need this information, so I'm not mapping it in `Inspection.hbm.xml`.

When I do need the info, I want to take an IEnumerable collection of `Inspections`, query the database to find their `LastCompletedDate`, and fill that in for each. Ideally, without making a separate trip to the database for each `Inspection`.  I'm having trouble finding a way to do this in NHibernate (I'm a relative newbie to NHibernate). I'm thinking of something like:

```
CurrentSession.CreateQuery(
                "select InspectionId, dbo.fn_GetLastCompletedDate(InspectionId) 
                 from Inspection where InspectionId in :idList")
              .SetParameter("idList", from InspectionList   select InspectionId)
              .List();
```

followed by a loop to pull out the dates and add them to the Inspection objects.

Is there a better way to do this? And what syntax do I need?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options which I can think of.

1. Mark the property as lazy load

   ```
   <property name="LastCompletedDate" 
             lazy="true" 
             formula="dbo.fn_GetLastCompletedDate(InspectionId)"/>
   ```

   When performing a query to get all Inspection objects this property will not be loaded.

   ```
   CurrentSession.CreateQuery("from Inspection")
                 .List<Inspection>();
   ```

   But when including a hint this property will be loaded along with all other properties.

   ```
   CurrentSession.CreateQuery("from Inspection fetch all properties")
                 .List<Inspection>();
   ```

   The disadvantage of this approach is that [this hint is only available when using HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826353/nhibernate-3-lazy-properties-and-eager-queries). Further details can be found here

   http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties
2. The second option is to use a component with lazy load enabled.

   ```
   <component name="lazy_load_items" lazy="true">        
        <property name="LastCompletedDate" 
                  formula="dbo.fn_GetLastCompletedDate(InspectionId)"/>
   </component>
   ```

   Again this is lazy loaded so a normal query against the Inspection entity wouldn't result in the function being called for each row

   ```
   CurrentSession.QueryOver<Inspection>.List();
   ```

   But it can be eager loaded via any of the query APIs

   ```
   session.QueryOver<Inspection>()
          .Fetch(i => i.lazy_load_items).Eager
          .List();
   ```

   This disadvantage of this approach is that is requires an extra class to be created just to contain your single property.

   #### UPDATE

   On further testing it looks like eager loading of components only works with HQL using the `fetch all properties` hint. So the query example I gave is wrong and therefore so are the advantages for the component approach.

Comment: The lazy load caused other problems elsewhere in the code. So I wound up just doing a straight SQL query to pass back the data I needed, and manually inserted it into the Inspection objects.

Comment: @MikeKantor I'm sorry my suggestions didn't help you. Good luck with your project.